# How to setup gradle with Intellij IDEA with WSL2 project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a project cloned inside [ubuntu wsl](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\project`. Opened it inside Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.1.3 and tried to import as gradle project, but I am getting uninformative error message: [image]

Here's my gradle config in IDEA:
[image]

The question is how should I open my project in IDEA then?

**EDIT:**

Logs from imported project contain this stack trace. Possibly this causes the issue.

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$DistributionWrapper.getToolingImplementationClasspath(GradleConnectorService.kt:287)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:147)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect function
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1161)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1165)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:55)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionInstaller.install(DistributionInstaller.java:72)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:133)
    ... 15 more
```

**EDIT2:**
Attaching full logs of instantiating new project with `gradle init` command:
https://pastebin.com/G4xhR3N3

Comment: Does it show more informationif you click on top level element ("backend")?

Comment: No, on the top level is a blank page.

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after reimporting project?

Comment: My guess is that this is not a supported use case yet. There are open tickets for supporting WSL fully in IntelliJ. If it is of interest to you, go vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223986 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171510. Also check out https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235720.

Comment: @y.bedrov updated question with stack trace from IDEA logs

Comment: This is a bug in IDEA, Gradle, or more likely the JRE under WSL. You aren't going to be able to work around it. Go add your bug reports and votes to the issues that @BjørnVester mentioned, and hope that JetBrains gets around to fixing it soon.

Comment: @IanKemp You are right, they are still have this issue even with the latest EAP version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235720#focus=Comments-27-4264504.0-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains released 2021.1 version of Intellij IDEA with more support for WSL 2. And now it's possible to import projects from Ubuntu mount using Gradle and Maven. https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/intellij-idea-2021-1-eap-1/

Comment: kinda, seems to mangle pathing.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround that was useful in my case (I have WSL 2):

- Create a project folder in your Windows filesystem.
- Using mklink and mklink /D, create symbolic links to your WSL files and folders (I have the WSL 2 filesystem, \wsl$, mounted as my L: drive, probably this is a requirement). The mklink command requires to be run as Administrator (run cmd.exe as Admin). Example: "mklink /D src L:\home\john\project\src". List of files that I sym-linked:

  - <s><SYMLINKD> .git/</s> (**edit:** git support in Windows side doesn't work with this approach, as git detects the difference between symlinks and regular files; however, you can still use git on WSL).
  - <SYMLINK> .gitignore
  - <SYMLINK> build.gradle
  - <SYMLINK> settings.gradle
  - <SYMLINKD> src/
- Notice .gradle, gradle, gradew, gradlew.bat, and .idea don't have symbolic links. WSL should have its own .gradle and build folders, and no IntelliJ gradle wrapper.
- IntelliJ Gradle and WSL gradle should work fine and independently this way.